# How I can refresh the DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to refresh a DataGridView when I update some row in other Form. I'm loading the DataGridView in the load event in this way:

```
Private Sub Home_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
       (... Nothing important...)

        Me.StockBasicoTableAdapter1.FillByOwner(Me.SctmpruebasDataSet.StockBasico, idCompany)

    Catch exception As Exception
        BarraEstado.Text = exception.Message
    End Try

End Sub
```

So, when I have the data updated, I use REST to send it to my Java API and I update the data in my DB. So my problem is I don't have any idea to how I can update the DataGridView in the Home form to see the row updated.

```
 Private Sub BtnRegularizar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnRegularizar.Click, MyBase.Enter
    Try
       (... Here I update all the data ...)

        VariablesGlobales.PutRequest("http://localhost:8084/SCTM/api/UpdateBulto", bulto.ToString)

        Dim _dialogSuccess As OperacionCompletada = New OperacionCompletada()
        _dialogSuccess.Owner = Me
        _dialogSuccess.ShowDialog()

        Dim company = VariablesGlobales.usuario.Item("company")
        Dim idCompany = Integer.Parse(company.Item("idCompany").ToString)

        Home.StockBasicoTableAdapter1.FillByOwner(Home.SctmpruebasDataSet.StockBasico, idCompany)
    Catch exception As Exception
        Me.BarraEstado.Text = exception.Message()
    End Try
End Sub
```

I used this way, `Home.DataGridView1.refresh()` even both at once, without any result.

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: in Btn_Reguralizar_Click after End Try put  DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSoutce or data_from DB

Answer (score 0):

`refresh` method has nothing to do with it, it only repaints the control.

Check the following link for details regarding refresh method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh(v=vs.110).aspx

You need to reset the `datasource` of `gridview` control.

Example:

```
Home.DataGridView1.DataSource = you_data_object
```

Answer (score 0):

and see here how is done more elegant, **Step by Step**  :

```
 'Open the mountains file geodatabase feature class
  Dim mountainsTable As Table = Table.OpenFileGeodatabaseTable("C:\Data\Romania.gdb", "mountains")

  'Create a new TableBindingAdapter object for the mountains Table
  Dim tableAdapter As TableBindingAdapter = New TableBindingAdapter(mountainsTable)

  'Set the UseCodedValueDomains property to display the descriptive name for the values in any
  'columns which have a CodedValueDomainDefined
  tableAdapter.UseCodedValueDomains = True

  'Set the UseColumnAliasNames property to display alias names in the Column headers.
  tableAdapter.UseColumnAliasNames = True

  'Fill the adapter with all the rows from the mountains Table
  tableAdapter.Fill()

  'Note that the BindingSource component and the DataGridView control would normally be
  'instantiated by dragging and dropping them onto a Windows Form from the toolbox.


  'Create a new BindingSource component
  Dim bindingSource1 As System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource = New System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource()
  'Set the DataSource to be the tableAdapter object
  bindingSource1.DataSource = tableAdapter

  'Create a DataGridView control
  Dim dataGridView1 As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView()
  'Set the Datasource to be the bindingSource1 object 
   dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1
```